# I can't return the result and I can't get a value from the main function for function

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Question:

> Have the function ClosestEnemy(arr) take the array of numbers stored in arr and from the position  in the array where a 1 is, return the number of spaces either left or right you must move to reach  an enemy which is represented by a 2. For example: if arr is [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2] then your  program should return 3 because the closest enemy (2) is 3 spaces away from the 1. The array will  contain any number of 0's and 2's, but only a single 1. It may not contain any 2's at all as well,  where in that case your program should return a 0.

My problem `Console.Readline()` and  `return`.I dont know proper use.

I get to this errors, I put a comment line on the code

> CS1503 C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'int[]'
>
> CS0165 C# Use of unassigned local variable 'result'

examples:

> Input: new int[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2}

Output: 4

> Input: new int[] {2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0}

Output: 1

```
public static int ClosestEnemy1(int[] arr)
        {
            int result;
            int counterright = 0;
            int counterleft = 0;
            int locationleft = 0;
            int location1 = 0;
            int locationright = 0;
            int rightclosest;
            int leftclosest;
            int i;
            // code goes here  
            for(i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] == 1)
                {
                    location1 = i;//1'in konumu belirlendi
                }
            }
            //sağa kontrol et

               while (arr[i]!= '\0' )//saga bak
            {
                i = location1;
                i++;
               if (arr[i] == 2)
                {
                    counterright = 1;
                    locationright = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (i = location1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (arr[i] == 2) 
                {
                    counterleft = 1;
                    locationleft = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(counterright == 0 && counterleft == 0)
            {
                result=0;
            }
            if(counterright == 0 && counterleft == 1)
            {
              result = location1 - locationleft;

            }
            if(counterright == 1 && counterleft == 0)
            {
                result = locationright - location1;

            }
            if(counterright == 1 && counterleft == 1)
            {
                leftclosest = location1 - locationleft;
                rightclosest = locationright - location1;
                if (leftclosest > rightclosest)
                {
                   result = leftclosest;
                }
                else
                {
                    result= rightclosest; 
                }
            }
            return result; //it's error!!!!!!!
           }

        static void Main()
        {
            // keep this function call here
            Console.WriteLine(ClosestEnemy1(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())));//it's errorr!!!!
        }
```

Comment: you need first to declare variable then process it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these corrections in your code:

1) chnage input type to string : `public static int ClosestEnemy1(string inputString)` 
, make sure you leave the comment for user to enter input like this: `1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2`

2) inside the function make `int arr[]` by String.Split():

```
string[] stringNumbers = inputString .Split(',');
int[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(stringNumbers, s => int.Parse(s));
```

3) change this line :
`int result=0;` to assign the default value to `result` .

4) assign `i=0` or what you think better before while, becuse the last assigned value for `i` is `7` and it will has an error.

```
    //sağa kontrol et
    i = 0;
    while (arr[i] != '\0')//saga bak
```

5) in the main() function after you get console result, put a `Console.ReadKey();` to you see the result.